# Edit not working for newly added data - knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have been following some tutorials and trying to follow `knockout.js`. I am not able to edit any data that is newly added.

My JS Code:

```
var data = [
new ListData("Programmer", 1),
new ListData("Testing", 2),
new ListData("DBA", 3),
new ListData("Lead", 4),
new ListData("Manager", 5)
];


function ListData(desig, id) {
    return {
        Desig: ko.observable(desig),
        Id: ko.observable(id)

    };
}
var viewModel = {
    list: ko.observableArray(data),
    dataToAdd: ko.observable(""),
    selectedData: ko.observable(null),

    addTag: function () {
        this.list.push({ Desig: this.dataToAdd() });
        this.tagToAdd("");
    },

    selecData: function () {
        viewModel.selectedData(this);
    }
};

$(document).on("click", ".editData", function () {
});

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

My View Code:

```
    <input type="text" data-bind="value:   dataToAdd" />
    <button data-bind="click: addData">
        + Add
    </button>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: list">
        <li data-bind="click: $parent.selecData">
            <span data-bind="text: Desig"></span>
            <div>
                <a href="#" class="editData">Edit</a> 
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
<div id="EditData" data-bind="with: selectedData">
    Designation:
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: Desig" />
</div>
```

I am able to edit the data which already exists like - Programmer, Testing, DBA...but if I add a new data..I am not able to edit. Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `addData` (you named it `addTag` in the code, but call `addData` in the HTML) function doesn't construct new elements the same way your initial data creation does. Note: since your `ListData` constructor explicitly returns an object, `new` is superfluous.

```
addData: function () {
    this.list.push(ListData(this.dataToAdd(), ""));
},
```